# How to test TypeScript abstract class with Jasmine

Tags: angular, typescript, testing, jasmine

I have a very simple abstract class which I implement in my Angular service.  I am trying to write some tests for it but cannot find any information about testing abstract classes in the Jasmine docs.

```
import { Page } from '../models/index';

import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

export abstract class ILayoutGeneratorService {
  abstract generateTemplate(page: Page, deviceType: string ): Observable<string>;
}
```

The abstract class is implemented as follows:

```
export class DefaultLayoutGeneratorService implements ILayoutGeneratorService { 
      generateTemplate(page: Page, deviceType: string): Observable<string> { 
        return Observable.create((observer: any) => {
           // do something with result. 
        }); 
}
```

I am wondering how I would write a basic isolated unit test that checks if the class above can be implemented and its single method called.  I understand that I would somehow have to mock the implementation of the class, but I am not really sure how to go about this.

Comment: what kind of test do you have in mind? show the specific test case

Comment: I have updated with the implementation ( see above )

Comment: did you delete your comment?

Comment: No I just moved the implementation to the original question. Look above.

Comment: you can't test if abstract class can be implemented... you even can't test if class is abstract or not, because tests run on JavaScript and JavaScript doesn't have abstract classes

Comment: Correct, it is just transpiled to JS, but I was wondering if there was some clever way of doing this that I was not aware of.

Comment: not as far as I know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not aware of an approach to automatically stub out an implementation of an abstract class in TypeScript. If you find one, that's a good bet. But with `spyOn` and related behaviors, Jasmine can at least help.

A couple approaches along those lines:

1. You already have an implementation in your `DefaultLayoutGeneratorService`, so you could leverage that as your mock implementation as well, especially coupled with `spyOn`, e.g.:

   ```
   let defaultLayoutGeneratorService = new DefaultLayoutGeneratorService();
   spyOn(defaultLayoutGeneratorService, 'generateTemplate');
   ```

   If you need to test several specific outputs, you could use that together with `.and.returnValue`, e.g.:

   ```
   spyOn(...).and.returnValue(Observable.of('hello'));
   ```
2. Or you could implement a separate mock. (Maybe because `DefaultLayoutGeneratorService` is difficult to instantiate, or just to decouple.) If you want to test specific outputs or just decouple test logic from the mock, you could still use `spyOn` as above.

Then call the various methods to be tested, like `mock.generateTemplate(page, deviceType)`. And include whatever additional checks that you need, probably leveraging Jasmine's `expect`.